# Using getJSON() on CakePHP framework

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, cakephp

I'm using AJAX to check whether a username is in the database or not. Here is the controller code:

```
public function check_username(){
    if($this->request->is('json')){
        $user = $this->User->find('count', array('conditions' => array('username' => $this->request->data['username'])));
        if($user === 0)
            echo '1';
        else
            echo false;
    }
    $this->autoRender = false;
}
```

And I used AJAX on the view. That was ok and now I'm trying to use Json and changed my controller code to:

```
public function check_username(){
    if($this->request->is('json')){
        $user = $this->User->find('count', array('conditions' => array('username' => $this->request->data['username'])));
        echo json_encode($user);
    }
    $this->autoRender = false;
}
```

This is my view code. This isn't working (no alert is being appeared):

```
var un = $('#username').val();
$.getJSON(
    '/oes/users/check_username',
    {username:un},
    function(result){
    alert(result);
});
```

Now anybody please help me make it working. I'm also new to Json.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: not familiar with CAKE...but this looks suspicious `if($this->request->is('json')){` you aren't sending any json, nor any get param  `json`.  Inspect request in browser console to see if it is being made, status, response etc

Comment: Thank you for taking my problem in mind though you don't familiar with CakePHP. `$this->request->is('json')` just checks if the request is `json` or not. I've also tried commenting this. Can you please say me the raw php way?

Comment: did you inspect request in console? Need to know which end is causing problems, or both

Comment: No, I can't use console. That doesn't just appear (the console window). Then what should I do?

Comment: what do you mean can't use console? Hit F12 in any modern browser. If you're going to use ajax...better get familiar with it, is first line of troubleshooting

Comment: ok. Didn't know that. So, how can I inspect request?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40906/discussion-between-coolbrain-and-charlietfl)

Comment: Your code is full of wrong. Read up about [JsonView](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html) on the CakePHP manual.

Comment: Why not just use jQuery's `$.ajax` or `$.post`?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function check_username(){
    if($this->request->is('json')){
        $user = $this->User->find('count', array('conditions' => array('username' => $this->request->data['username'])));
        echo json_encode($user);
        exit;

    }
    $this->autoRender = false;
}
```

if it works , that the problem comes from loading view , (due to autoRender=false);